# Почему у меня не работает множественный список в Android?

Tags: android, listview

Вот мой код:

```
headingCursor =  db.rawQuery("select * from "+ SubscriptionHelper.TABLE_HEADING, null);
// определяем, какие столбцы из курсора будут выводиться
String[] headings = new String[] {SubscriptionHelper.COLUMN_HEADING_NAME};
// создаем адаптер, передаем в него курсор
headingAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
                headingCursor, degrees, new int[]{android.R.id.text1}, 0);
listHeading.setAdapter(headingAdapter);
listHeading.setItemsCanFocus(false);
listHeading.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

Проблема заключаться в том, что на экране у меня отображается обычный список:
[image: мой список вот такой]

Я хочу, чтобы у каждого элемента был типа чекбокс:

[image: вот такое я хочу получить]

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Эникейщик мной был изучен данный вопрос, и я не смогла разобраться. считаю свой вопрос полным, а ваш комментарий не информативным.

Comment: Ну ждите ответа, как соловей лета. Может быть, найдется кто-то, кто поймет что вы делаете не так, особенно если учесть, что неизвестно, как выглядит "так". Чмоки.

Comment: @Ульяна ваш вопрос не полный. В нём не хватает описания того, что пошло нет так. В данный момент не ясно имеется ли у вас какая-то ошибка компиляции или времени исполнения. Если это они, то нужны сообщения компилятора или логи падения. Если дело не в этом, а у вас что-то на экране не отображается или отображается не так - надо об этом написать. Без этого вам сложно помочь, ибо не ясно что за проблема.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб большое спасибо за объяснение! поправила

Comment: @Ульяна, а вы уверены, что оно должно так работать - т.е. что добавление `.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);` будет добавлять чекбоксы? Я точно не уверен (ListView и готовые адаптеры не использовал лет 5), но мне кажется, что оно так не будет работать. И надо делать свой адаптер, свою разметку для ячейки списка и свой обработчик для чекбокса.Ну и использовать RecyclerView вместо ListView.И ещё не использовать курсоры, а брать либу Room для работы с БД.Т.е.я бы эту задачу решал бы на нескольких сотнях строк кода минимум,не рассчитывая на какие-то готовые решения на ListView и Cursor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело было в адаптаре, он должен был быть таким:

```
headingAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
                headingCursor, degrees, new int[]{android.R.id.text1}, 0);
```